# What's the equivalent to && when writing a bash script?

Tags: bash, centos, scripting

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.  I did make an effort to search/check before asking here.

I'm comfortable with writing one-liners like this:

```
foocommand && foocommand2 && foocommand3
```

The idea being that I only want subsequent commands to run if the previous one was "successful".

I'm writing a somewhat lengthy script and this one-liner isn't feasible because it looks like a huge block of confusing code to everyone else.

I want to space out the commands and write comments inbetween them in the script.  How can I do this and still have the equivalent of && in there?

Comment: This bears repeating: `&&` doesn't mean the subsequent command will run if the previous *one* was successful. It means the command will run if the *collective result* of *all* the previous commands in the command list is success. You may know this, but future readers may misunderstand.

Comment: Also just as a note, this behavior you're describing that comes from `||`and `&&` (as opposed to `|` or `&`) is called short circuiting. The behavior used with the latter operators is called eager evaluation.

Comment: @kojiro: I don't see the distinction. `a && b && c` will only run `b` if `a` succeeds, so "it only runs `c` if `b` succeeds" and "it only runs `c` if `a` and `b` both succeed" are equivalent statements: `b` can't succeed unless `a` succeeded.

Comment: @ruakh `a || b && c` is more illustrative.

Comment: @ruakh no, `true || false && echo hi` will output `hi`. [The specification reads,](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03) *The operators "&&" and "||" shall have equal precedence and shall be evaluated with left associativity.*

Comment: @kojiro: Whoops, thanks for the correction. I see what you mean, then. :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -lh &&
    # This is a comment
    echo 'Wicked, it works!'
```

I hope I understood what you asked correctly.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the closest to what I was hoping to do.  And it makes it very easy to convert back into a one liner if needed.

Comment: Mike, since you're concerned about code cleanliness, a common convention is to indent the 2-N sections of the chain underneath the first.

Comment: @jblaine I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Mike, Stackexchange won't let me format my answer properly, so here is all I meant: [indent](https://gist.github.com/jblaine/5304258)

Comment: @jblaine Good point, edited to indent the lines.

Answer (score 40):

You can change the shebang line to

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

After any error, the script will stop.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll keep that in mind.  Thank you.

Comment: saves me from typing set -e when I need it

Comment: @Silverrocker It is POSIX too (except for the `bash` part of course). The POSIX shell takes a bunch of options that are applicable to `set`. Or vice versa? `set` is a way of setting shell command line options within the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a number of standard utilities that don't follow the usual exit-status conventions, so `-e` can misbehave. For example, you probably don't want your script to terminate every time you `diff` two non-identical files. You can, of course, work around this by appending `|| true` (or perhaps `|| [ $? = 1 ]`) to such commands, but the OP mentions an "everyone else" who will have to read this script, and said "everyone else" will probably not be used to having to cope with `-e`.

Comment: @ruakh: I find the exit status of `let x++` for `x=0` even worse. But I still use it sometimes. It really depends on what commands you need.

Comment: I used to put the `-e` on the she-bang, until one admin of my company kept launching my scripts with `bash myscript.sh`, so it ignored the `-e`. Now all my scripts have a `set -e` in the second line.

Answer (score 19):

If you don't like the `set -e` idea, maybe you can invert the logic.

```
foocommand || exit 1
foocommand2 || exit 2
foocommand3 || exit 3
```

More usefully, replace `exit` with something to print a useful error message, then exit. Inside a function, of course, you want `return` instead of `exit`.

Comment: Or `foocommand || exit` to exit with `foocommand`'s exit status if non-zero.

Comment: How does this work? Is it like in C - if the left argument evaluates to TRUE, the no more arguments are checked?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's a common idiom in Lisp (and functional languages in general, I suppose) and in Perl.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `if else fi` blocks instead.

```
if foocommand; then

  # some comments

  if foocommand2; then

    # more comments

    foocommand3
  fi
fi
```

It's a little more readable.

Alternatively you can just use `\` to break your big 1 liner into several lines

```
foocommand && \
  # some comment
  foocommand2 && \
    # more comment
    foocommand3
```

But of course this can be confusing to the untrained eye.

Comment: I don't think the ``\`` is necessary there.

Comment: You are right. Force of habit.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider using nested `if` statements. Other option is to use curly's to group like `{ true && echo hi; } || echo huh`

**Update 1:**

Here's an example without newlines/comments:

```
{ { false && echo "inner true"; } && { echo "inner true" && true; } || { echo "inner false" && false; } || echo "outter false"; }
```

Comment: @Stephane Thanks for adding semicolon.  I've been using my phone to reply so I haven't been double checking my answers. :)

Comment: Interesting idea.  Yeah, I had thought of nested if statements but if I'm chaining a lot of stuff together it might get messy.

Answer (score 4):

Split each sequence of commands into functions:

```
big_block_1() {
  # ...
}
big_block_2() {
  # ...
}
big_block_3() {
  # ...
}

big_block_1 && big_block_2 && big_block_3
```

Answer (score 0):

I always like to write a "fail" function which lets me specify the thing I was going to do when the failure occurred and then use the `||` pattern.  Like the following:

```
function fail() {
  echo "Failure: ${@}"
  exit 1
}

foocommand || fail "couldn't foo"
```